# Open WooCommerce External Products in New Tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to customize WooCommerce external product links to open in new tabs...

This is my try:

added a filter to the WordPress theme **functions.php** file as the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'woocommerce_externalProducts_openInNewTab' );

function woocommerce_externalProducts_openInNewTab($product_url) {

    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('external') ) {
        $product_url = $product->get_product_url() . '"target="_blank""';
    }

    return $product_url;

}
```

What did I missed?

Comment: this will not work because url is a link... you're adding some texts to a link, that's what you are doing now..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you're currently doing is wrong... `get_product_url` is named as what it do. It will give you the url... not the html anchor that has the url, but just the url.. so you're just adding some text to the url.. that's what you are doing...

One solution is given by @Ash Patel. You can change the markup by using templates... just navigate to your plugin folder and look for this file.. `woocommerce\templates\single-product\add-to-cart\external.php`. You can find instructions inside it.

Now, sometimes, we don't like editing templates... especially if it's just minor edits like this...

Below code will do it the way you want it... just paste this code in your theme's `functions.php`.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'rei_external_add_to_cart', 30 );
function rei_external_add_to_cart(){

    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->add_to_cart_url() ) {
        return;
    }

    $product_url = $product->add_to_cart_url();
    $button_text = $product->single_add_to_cart_text();

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
    <p class="cart">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_url ); ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $button_text ); ?></a>
    </p>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Reigel, would you please explain to me what `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' );` and `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' );` do?

Comment: those are included in the template.. for consistency, I put it... you can remove it without worries...

Comment: Another question, please... now, my theme's <a> already has new classes, what if I want to keep them and don't replace them by what you added: `class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"` ?

Comment: I've added these classes to your answer, but the <a> style changed!

Comment: you can do anything as you please.. just make sure there's no php errors ;)

Comment: the same as how we are free to add `target="_blank"` :D

Comment: yeah, I didn't noticed another HTML markup was under it! thank you very much @Reigel

Comment: This only works for the product archive, not the single product listing.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you add `target="_blank"` to the links on archive pages:

```
function ns_open_in_new_tab($args, $product) 
{
    if( $product->is_type('external') ) {
        // Inject target="_blank" into the attributes array
        $args['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
    }    

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'ns_open_in_new_tab', 10, 2 );
```

Replace `ns_` part with your own namespace abbreviation.

Answer (score 2):

Remove above funtion from function.php:

Use plugin files from Template folder by Template Overwrite method and then

follow below path:
woocommerce\templates\single-product\add-to-cart\external.php

open external.php where there is a tag, apply target="_blank".

it will work.

Comment: i mean you can use plugin file from your theme directory by use template overwrite and apply code without disturb plugin files.

Comment: you can rephrase your answer above.